# EC2 Instance scheduled for retirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Facing one problem with ec2 during last week I have upgraded my ec2 from `c3.2xlarge` to `m4.2xlarge` and again after few hours I have down grade to `c3.2xlarge` and working fine. At next day I got an email from AWS for `"EC2 Instance scheduled for retirement"` and my ec2 is stooped.

I have started ec2 again its working fine but not sure any other point need to take care or not can any one help me here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon generally destroys the hardware periodically, if your instance is on that rack then you will get notified that instance will get retire after certain period.

**If you stop and start the instance, Amazon by default will move your instance to different rack**.

I am not exactly sure of the time period but last time I have checked they destroy their hardware after 2 years.

Usually you will get notified months before instance is terminated.

Thus **stop and start** the instance will work note **not restart**.

**Edit:**
Here is the reference [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply @harshal, You mean no need to take any other action here?

Comment: Nope, stop and start will do.

Comment: c3.2xlarge use EBS and m4.2xlarge use instance store volume is this cause this might be but currently its working fine.

Comment: Normally, if the hardware is working, but scheduled to be decommissioned. Your instance will keep running. However you should start/stop as soon as possible. If the host failed, your instance will generally stop immediately. The host may be recovered, or it may be removed from the host pool. Just starting it again will get a new host. Instance storage, if enabled, does not survive.

Comment: Note that as c3.* instances have (ephemeral) instance store disks, you will lose any data on the disk when you stop the instance.   If you only have data on the root disk, though, which is EBS, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take an image of your instance and launch a new instance from it. Then terminate your old instance. We have had the same issue several times.